# When installing Ubuntu from a disk, will it overwrite my current Mac OS partition automatically?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a disk formatted to install Ubuntu. When I boot from this disk, I get a menu, with an option that says "Install" (or possibly "Install Ubuntu", I have pretty bad memory). If I choose this option, will Ubuntu automatically overwrite my current Mac partition without consulting me? I'm using OS X El Capitan, Version 10.11.6, and am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: No, it won't. You will get a setup wizard that allows for the partitioning of the drive. BTW you can choose "try" and then open the installer while you are running the live OS.

Comment: Thanks! Do you recommend booting the trial and using the installer or just directly installing?

Comment: I prefer the former... That way you can connect using a browser in case of any issue. Moreover you can also run other programs to test everything, like the webcam, the printer and so on.

Comment: I'm in the installation process and a little confused with the process to partition my disk. How do I select the proper device to partition, and how do I partition it?

Comment: @maknel If it gives you the option, select "Install Ubuntu alongside Mac OS X". Otherwise, you'll need to do a bit of reading. Here's where to start: [PartitioningSchemes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes)

Comment: @maknel This question looks a bit abandoned. If one or the answers helped you, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Also, consider upvoting all the answers you think are useful.

Answer (score 0):

It will not uninstall macOS unless you click on "Erase drive and install Ubuntu". Click on "Install Ubuntu".

Answer (score 0):

> If I choose this option, will Ubuntu automatically overwrite my current Mac partition without consulting me?

No, it won't. **You will get a setup wizard** that allows for the partitioning of the drive.

Keep in mind that you can choose *Try Ubuntu* and then open the installer while you are running the live OS. This is better, in my opinion, because then you can:

- connect using a browser in case of any issue
- use Gparted for advanced partitioning
- also run other programs if you need to write some documents or simply play while you are installing the OS
- test everything, like the webcam, the printer and so on

As pointed out by wjandrea in the comments, if the *Install Ubuntu alongside OS X* does not show up, you will need to perform manual partitioning.

See also:

- [Partitioning Schemes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes)
- [Mactel Community Help Pages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages)